# What does zero value means when pressing w in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am writing to ask what the **zero value (:0)** means in the **FROM** column after the **command `w` in bash**.

USER     TTY      **FROM**             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please use code formatting for commands (the `{}` button, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and not bold. We need to see the _exact_ command. Also, remember that commands are case sensitive. There is no `W` command, should we assume you mean `w`? Finally, please show us the actual output you are seeing (you can change IPs to `1.2.3.4` but there's nothing else sensitive there). Are you sure you are not looking at the `TTY` column? I don't know of a `w` that has a FROM column, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Hello , thank you . I made the necessary edits and the question answered . Thank you again for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking/asking about the command `w` (I don't know a `W` command):
It usually tells, from where a user is logged in. `:0` is the `$DISPLAY`, when the user is logged in locally.